# Kotlin coroutines delay do not work on IOS queue dispatcher

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I have a KMM app, and there is code:

```kotlin
fun getWeather(callback: (WeatherInfo) -> Unit) {
        println("Start loading")
        GlobalScope.launch(ApplicationDispatcher) {
            while (true) {
                val response = httpClient.get<String>(API_URL) {
                    url.parameters.apply {
                        set("q", "Moscow")
                        set("units", "metric")
                        set("appid", weatherApiKey())
                    }
                    println(url.build())
                }
                val result = Json {
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                }.decodeFromString<WeatherApiResponse>(response).main
                callback(result)

                // because ApplicationDispatcher on IOS do not support delay
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { delay(DELAY_TIME) }
            }
        }
    }
```

And if I replace `withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { delay(DELAY_TIME) }` with `delay(DELAY_TIME)` execution is never returned to while cycle and it will have only one iteration.

And `ApplicationDispatcher` for IOS looks like:

```kotlin
internal actual val ApplicationDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = NsQueueDispatcher(dispatch_get_main_queue())

internal class NsQueueDispatcher(
    private val dispatchQueue: dispatch_queue_t
) : CoroutineDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        dispatch_async(dispatchQueue) {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

And from `delay` source code I can guess, that `DefaultDelay` should be returned and there is should be similar behaviour with/without `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`

```kotlin
/** Returns [Delay] implementation of the given context */
internal val CoroutineContext.delay: Delay get() = get(ContinuationInterceptor) as? Delay ?: DefaultDelay
```

Thanks!

P.S. I got `ApplicationDispatcher` from [ktor-samples](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/master/client-mpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `ApplicationDispatcher` is some old stuff, you don't need to use it anymore:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

}
```

or

```
MainScope().launch {

}
```

And don't forget to use `-native-mt` version of coroutines, more info in this [issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2363)

Comment: Thanks! For me first variant throws exceptions from Android because I change UI in the callback. But `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` works well for both Android and IOS

Comment: you use first variant to run on a background queue, and second one for main queue. I think `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` should be equivalent to the second one. So if you're doing some huge calculations run those on the inside first one, and when you finish call ui updates inside second one, to come back to UI thread

Comment: Generally you should avoid GlobalScope, as you lose the benefits of structured concurrency. Alternatively you can save a reference to MainScope() in your ViewModel, or similar - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-guide.html#additional-references

Comment: I found a lot of interesting in [structured-concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency), thanks @enyciaa !